# How to split words in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-manipulation

In Excel, how do I split a word from cell A1 in all possibilities of 3 sequenced letters?

Example:

If cell A1 contains word `university`, I need that it generates following text in the other cells:

```
B1=uni
C1=niv
D1=ive
E1=ver
F1=ers
G1=rsi
H1=sit
I1=ity
```

Comment: In B1: `=MID(A$1,COL()-1,3)` and fill right.

Comment: Dear, thanks for the answer, however this formula is coming up with B1=uni, C1=ni (incomplete), and the other ones didnt come up with the results above. Would you know how to complete C1 and also do D1 to I1 as well?

Comment: My mistake - the $ is in the wrong place.Try `=MID($A1,COL()-1,3)`.

Comment: Hello, formula is working, however when it finishes the word, which is I1=ity, it continues with J1=ty and with K1:y, which dont have 3 characters. How do we could do to stop the formula when there are less then 3 characters as result?

Comment: OK, I understand now that the formula should handle any length word, and stop after the final triplet.  I'm back to my computer now, so I will post a full, tested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will list all possible (sequential) 3-letter combinations in a word, and terminate the list after the last triplet.

`=IF(LEN($A1)>COLUMN(),MID($A1,COLUMN()-1,3),"")`

Here is an example data table:

[image]

Best regards.  Sorry this took so long to get straight. And for the self-referential data table.  :-D

Comment: Hello, this works perfect. One last thing, while writting the formula, is necessary to pull it to all the cells horizontally and vertically so it uses the formula to calculate until column L and line 10. Is there an automated way it could perform this action into all lines of column A and display direcly all columns and lines results without pulling it by hand to left and down? Thank you

Comment: In Excel, a cell must have a formula in it for a calculated result to appear in that cell.  So the formula must be filled to the right and down into every cell  in the data table. There are faster ways to copy the formula, though. You could type the formula in the top left cell, then click that cell and type CTRL-C. Shift click in the bottom right cell to select the entire range, and type CTRL-V.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-(ROW(A1)-1)),3)
```

[image]

Please make sure the absolute reference and relative reference correct in the formula.

For Row 1 try this formula:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-(COLUMN(A1)-1)),3)
```

[image]

Comment: See comment above.

Comment: Change formula to `=LEFT(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-(COLUMN(A1)-1)),3)`

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you. The formula =LEFT(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-(COLUMN(A1)-1)),3) is giving the result for 1 row only and not deleting the less than 3 characters if continue pulling the formula onwards.

Answer (score 0):

This Formula will help you to Split the Cell Value into the same Row.

Check the Screen Shot below.

[image]

```
=MID($A1, COLUMNS($B$1:B$1), 3)
```

*Note, Write Formula in Cell B1 and drag the Formula right till Cell I1.*

**NB:** If required you can adjust the Length of the Characters you are extracting into Rows, just by replace **3** with required Length Value.

Comment: OP asked for the results to be in row 1, not column B.

Comment: @Bandersnatch,,, Ohhhh great,, :-) ,, I missed the Cell address in first look . Let me alter the Formula.

Comment: @Bandersnatch,, it's corrected :-) .